# How to calculate the values inside the TR using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a scenario I need to calculate the values inside the tr using jQuery.

I have attached the below screenshot of the page where I need to calculate the working days of an employee and show the day count in NWD(NO of working days)

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what you have tried so far?Add your HTML+CODE-EFFORT

Comment: // grab the table, iterate over the tablerows, within the rows iterate over the cells and add the cell value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted your code,
here is how you would do it for a particular table row :)

```
  <table id="tableid">
    <tr id="first">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    var sum = 0;
    $("#tableid tr#first td").each(function(){
      var temp = parseInt($(this).html());
      sum += isNaN(temp)?0:temp;
    })
    console.log(sum)
  </script>
```